# What happens to current in a RC-battery circuit when you move plates with a square signal?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, physics, energy-harvesting

I use an RC circuit connected in series with a battery. I change the gap between plates of my air capacitor (2 paralleles plates, one fixe, the other one moving with an actuator) so as to change my capacitance with a square signal. I measure the tension at the resistor to know the current in my circuit. I do not understand the type of signal that I could expect ? what is happening ? What is the power harvested ?

**details:** Actually I am chemist working on composites for energy harvesting (converting motion into power). i would like to develop a circuit to easily quantify the power **harvestable** with my material under motion. These materials can actually change their permitivity under motion.[image]
To develop this circuit, my first step was to work with an air gap, to try to quantify the power harvestable and not harvested (we imagine that the material keeps its polarization). but i do not see how measure this value with these curves.. Do we have to integrate the signal ?

Comment: *What is the power harvested* **None, zero** all the energy comes from the battery and the energy needed to move the capacitor plate back and forth. Be careful when mentioning "energy harvesting" as it's a modern buzzword used by far too many people that do not understand what it means in practical terms.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54649/what-happens-to-capacitor-s-charge-when-the-plates-are-moved-further-apart

Comment: Piezo harvesting is certainly a thing e.g. http://www.piceramic.com/applications/piezo-energy-harvesting.html

Comment: This is a Q&A style site, you don't need to say thanks. Please read the guidelines in the help center: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask if you need to comment, don't edit your question, use the comments section

Answer (score 1):

The current in the resistor is equal to the rate of change of the charge in the capacitor :
$$i = \frac{d q}{dt}$$
where:
$$q = C v$$

In the general case [thanks to Chu], the current is then equal to:
$$i = C\frac{d v}{dt} + v\frac{d C}{dt}$$

In "standard" capacitors, the capacitance is a constant, and above equations can be simplified as the well-known relation:
$$i = C\frac{d v}{dt}$$
On the contrary, in your circuit, the capacitance is time dependent, and you cannot make the same simplification.

If you consider now that **voltage** is a constant (which is the case if your resistance is small enough, so voltage drop is negligible compared to the battery voltage), then \$\frac{d v}{dt}=0\$ and:
$$i = v\frac{d C}{dt}$$
Thus, the current is proportional to the rate of change of the capacitance.
This principle is used in [condenser microphones](http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/microphones/condenser.html).

**[ADDED]** Where the energy comes from

I forgot the part of the question about energy.
Because of the DC voltage (bias) created by the battery, there is a small electrostatic force that tends to attract the two plates to one another. When you move the plates against this force (i.e. draw them apart), you convert mechanical energy into electric energy. If the plates get closer to one another, electric energy is converted into mechanical energy.

> Do we have to integrate the signal ?

You should integrate the current, and multiply by the battery voltage. In your plot, the base line is the battery voltage (U=32V). You should integrate the difference between the peak voltage and 32V (i.e. the voltage across the resistance), and then multiply by 32V to get the energy exchanged during one move.

$$ q=\int \frac{U_c - U}{R_l} dt$$
$$ {Energy} = q \times U $$

Note that both the current and the energy flow can only exist if there is a DC bias (the battery).

Answer (score 0):

You are driving a resistor and capacitor in series with a square wave.  The square wave can be thought of successive steps in opposite direction.  After each step, the voltages and currents will decay towards the steady state value exponentially.

If the exponential time constant is large compared to the time between steps (half period of the square wave), then these exponentials will look largely linear.  If the time constant is small, then the steady state will have largely been reached before each new step.

In the steady state (driving voltage held for a long time relative to the R*C time constant), the current will be zero and the driving voltage will be across the capacitor.

Moving the distance between the capacitor plates changes the capacitance.  Wider separate results in lower capacitance.  Otherwise, this is just a simple R-C circuit, and can be analyzed as such.